# NSString to NSDate with format "2016-10-29 7 AM"

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to convert an NSString to NSDate, the string looks like "2016-10-29 7 AM". I tried different NSDate formats but nothing is working. I am getting the date right but not time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd h a` - [unicode.org Date Format Patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *str=@"2016-10-29 7 AM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd h a"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:str];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd h a"];
```